# Error in uploading Data bag from Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, chef-infra

I have designed code in ruby which converts my xls to json partially through spreadsheet and code. I need to upload this json to my data bag on chef-server. I am using knife commands from ruby code and running it. The json files upload to my local chef-repo correctly, but for transferring to chef-server  I am getting this error:

```
ERROR: Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed: Data Bag Items must contain a Hash or Mash!
```

I have validated the json, id matches name of file  and tried using [] braces at start and end but doesn't work. This is start of my json:

{
  "id": "default_1",
  "Sr.No" : "1", ....}

My ruby code essentials look like :

```
 require 'spreadsheet'
 book = Spreadsheet.open('BI.xls')
 sheet1 = book.worksheet('Sheet1') 
.
.
.
cmd1 = "cd #{current_dir}/chef-repo"
cmd2 = "knife data_bag create TestDB" #tried knife data bag too
cmd4 = "knife data_bag from file TestDB default_1.json" #tried knife data bag too

upload = %x[#{cmd1} && #{cmd2}  && #{cmd4} ]
puts "#{upload}"
```

The command `knife node list` shows nodes correctly. I am new to chef and ruby , searched and tried many things but not working.

Comment: Also, if I run the exact same command from my chef-repo, it works correctly and uploads the json to data bag.

Comment: To be sure, your json file path is `[...]/chef-repo/data_bags/TestDB/default_1.json` right ?

Comment: Yes it is, and code docs and .xls stored in chef-repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It surprisingly got sorted out! I stored all docs in chef-repo, and separated one file into  two, the first to convert .xls to json , and the other to execute knife commands . I now run both ruby scripts from chef-repo and the work just as expected. Phew!